# Send data from Android to Webservice to be inserted in my database

Tags: android, database, web-services, http-post

I'm trying to send a few variables(or data) for registration to a webservice from android throught "httppost" method. Here's the code.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsitename.com/webservice/register.php");
try {
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", et3.getText().toString()));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", et4.getText().toString()));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", et5.getText().toString()));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", et6.getText().toString()));
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
 httpclient.execute(httppost);

 } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 } catch (IOException e) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Following is the Register.php file code.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "myusername"; 
$pass = "mypass";
$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."<BR>");

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$db_select=mysql_select_db("the_db");
if(!$db_select){
    die(mysql_error());
    echo "error";
}

$query= "INSERT INTO USERS(fname, lname, userid, pass)
VALUES ('{$fname}', '{$lname}', '{$userid}', '{$pass}'); " ;

if($medo=mysql_query($query)){
    header("localhost/filename");
    exit;
}else{
    echo"<p> Error</p>";
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

When I try to run it, gives me an error. It says on my device that "YourApp has stopped working". Possibly a nullpointer exception or something like that. I don't know if this is the correct way to send simple variables like names and passwords etc. to the register.php. Can you tell me what the problem is here?

Comment: In the logcat it should give you a detailed error message and stack trace.  Look at that, or post it here.  Just an FYI-  one of the rules of Android is you can't use network IO on the main thread.  That may be your problem if you aren't calling this in an AsyncTask or thread.

Comment: try this http://www.hurl.it/ , here select POst service and pass parameters  so you can know problem

Comment: No I'm not calling it in and AsyncTask or thread. How do I do that? And how do I paste the logcat here? Sorry I'm a bit new with this stuff here.

Comment: Read the documentation on AsyncTask, it's pretty clear, and with a decent example. OR follow the recommendation in my answer since the AndroidAsyncHttpClient does all requests outside of your app’s main UI thread, but any callback logic will be executed on the same thread as the callback was created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the LogCat output. It should say at what line in which class you got an exception. Post the logcat output here if you need help. I would also recommend that you take a look at the [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). It greatly simplifies HTTP communication. Example of an HTTP POST:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
rp.put("fname", et3.getText().toString());
rp.put("lname", et4.getText().toString());
rp.put("userid", et5.getText().toString());
rp.put("pass", et6.getText().toString());

client.post("http://mywebsitename.com/webservice/register.php", rp, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public final void onSuccess(String response) {
        // handle your response here
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
        // something went wrong
    }               
});
```

Comment: Well with your code, there is no error now. But I think there is some problem with my php code.

Comment: Ok, so that's a different story then. Can you get the POST data on the PHP side, either using $_POST or $_REQUEST?

Comment: Sorry for replying late. I was actually busy with elections going on in my country. Anyways, could you please tell me how to check whether my php code is working correctly or not? Whether its recieving values or not? If it is, is it sending the values to the database or not? How do I check that?

Comment: Can you invoke the PHP code from a webpage and get it to work? Or try a browser plugin such as Poster (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-poster/cdjfedloinmbppobahmonnjigpmlajcd?hl=en, available for Firefox as well).

Comment: Your answer was helpful and I figured out the rest myself :). There were some typo mistakes while accessing the code. Thanks!